# Produce a quantum state with its density matrix an identity matrix up to an constant

Tags: qiskit, programming, quantum-state, density-matrix, state-preparation

For a n-qubit quantum state $|\psi\rangle=\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{2^N-1}|i\rangle$, by definition it's density matrix is $|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|=\displaystyle\sum_{i,j=0}^{2^N-1}|j\rangle\langle i|$.

Recently I am trying to implement a quantum neural network given by a [paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-020-14454-2), and one step of it is required so, maybe up to a normalization constant(at supplementary note 2, when calculating the derivative).

For a $2^N$ dimensional identity matrix, it **does not violate** the [requirements of being a density matrix](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/reinhold.bertlmann/pdfs/T2_Skript_Ch_9corr.pdf),  but I just cannot figure out how to do so and I even think this is not possible, have anybody be at this place before?

An additional requirement of mine is that the density matrix **must be produced by some qubits** or this problem might be truly tedious.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, I figured out by myself. When I was reading [this website](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/mathematics/density-matrix), it posts a density matrix that I want(that is a long website, to find the corresponding part, just search the keyword 'identity').

Here comes the method. To produce a $2^n$ dimensional density matrix, you need n qubits as ancilla and n qubits as the target. In the case of $n=1$, implement the $\hat H$ on the ancilla, then use a $cx$ gate with ancilla as the target.

The density matrix of the whole system is $\rho_{AB}=(\frac{|00\rangle+|11\rangle}{\sqrt2})(\frac{\langle 00|+ \langle 11|}{\sqrt2})$, and the density matrix of the target(the reduced density matrix) is $\rho_A=Tr_B(\rho_{AB})=\frac{1}{2}(|0\rangle\langle0|+|1\rangle\langle1|)=\frac{I_A}{2}$, which satisfies my requirement.

Comment: Although I did so, there might be space for us to improve the algorithm. In my answer, to produce an identity matrix(up to a normalization constant) of n qubits, another n ancilla qubits are required, but is this necessary?

Comment: I'm unsure why you want an identity matrix in the first place since its not a useful quantum state. Whether you can use fewer than n ancillas depends on the situation. If you're confident you can measure/reset the ancilla system without learning about the measurement result then you could prepare bell states between each qubit and the ancilla and measure the ancilla between each step, since $\frac{1}{2^n} I_{2^n} = (\frac{1}{2} I_2) \otimes \dots \otimes (\frac{1}{2} I_2) $.

Comment: Why the identity matrix useful for me comes from the nature communication 2020 article, Training Deep Neural Network.

Comment: I suspect there's something different going on than preparing a maximally mixed state. Once you have a maximally mixed state in your circuit, _you cannot do anything else with it_ - Any unitary will leave it maximally mixed, and so will any any valid CPTP map on one of its subspaces (this is easiest to see with Kraus form operators)

Comment: Your concern makes sense, but an identity density matrix is not all I need. Another quantum register is also required and there is additional unitaries act between the two quantum registers. The final output is the density matrices of the two registers.